# How can I edit text when I select an option?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to input text when I select the option "Other"

```
Spinner spn;
........
adapterString = new String[]
{
    "A",
    "B",
    "Other"
};
ArrayAdapter<String> adptLubricatorType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, adapterString);
spn.setAdapter(adptLubricatorType);
spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(listenerspn);
private Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener listenerspn = new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {


    }
```

How can I insert text when I pull down the spinner and choose "Other"?

I hope I can input like edittext and when I click other things,"Other" will change
to the string that I just input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an `EditText` always but set its visibility to `INVISIBLE` in XML file. Then when you detect that the selected item is `"Other"`, set VISIBILITY to `VISIBLE`. Something like

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
   //get the item selected item. Compare to the itme for which you want to make the EditText visible
   if( spn.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Other"){
       yourEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

}
```

Then you can handle the `EditText` as usual by having `onClickListener` etc. 
Hope you get the concept else please comment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create an alert dialog and add edit text to that:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setVisibility()` to toggle the visibility of the edittext.Here is the working code snippet,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    other = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.other);
    other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Spinner spn = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String[] adapterString = new String[]
    {
       "A",
       "B",
       "Other"
    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adptLubricatorType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, adapterString);
    spn.setAdapter(adptLubricatorType);

    Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener listenerspn = new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

}

**Layout file:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent>


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/other"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>
```